# How to hide/ignore part of code in my C# package if one particular another package dependency is not installed?

Tags: c#

I'm building package for my project in C#, and I want to reuse it across different projects.

Some Utility methods/classes in my package are dependent on another package (say RX .Net). But I know that I would use this package in projects without RX .Net installed.
For example I have class EmailSender, which has callback - style methods (void .Send(attrs, Action clb)) as well as RX based methods (IObservable .SendAsObservable(attrs)).

Could I do something like

```
#IF PACKAGE EXISTS RX.NET

# ENDIF
```

So parts of my code will be ignored if package does not exist?

Which is the best way to accomplish something like this without building 2 separate packages with duplicate class names etc.

Comment: I do not think this is possible, to be honest.

Comment: You can't. Simply loading your package will also try to load all dependencies. It would be a lot easier to have one core package with extra packages that add functionality for Rx or any other package, the way Microsoft.Extension.Logging or log4net do

Comment: Without knowing more about the layout of your projects it's difficult to be particularly helpful, but from your description it sounds like you might be better off breaking the package into 2 different packages.  One of them has the generic stuff that doesn't require this other package, and the other one does.  That way you can include `MyPackage` when you want the common one, and also include `MyPackageRx` when you want the one that has a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Investigate using a fake assembly in the references of your project:  adding a fake reference can resolve missing dlls: [Code generation, compilation, and naming conventions in Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/code-generation-compilation-and-naming-conventions-in-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_Configuring_code_generation_of_stubs)

Example of faking individual methods:
[Using Microsoft Fakes with mscorlib.dll](https://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/using-microsoft-fakes-with-mscorlib-dll)

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a legitimate method for stubbing in project references.

Comment: I suspect it was downvoted for being low quality.  It's not really helpful as an answer and would be more suited as a comment.  Maybe an example would make it a more suitable answer, if that's feasible.